# Executing mysqldump using Java program in MacOS

Tags: java, mysql, bash, netbeans-7, processbuilder

I'm using MacOS Mojave and mysqldump is set to path in `~/.bash_profile`

When using MacOS Terminal mysqldump is working.

Even with `/bin/bash -c mysqldump` it's working.

But when I try it with my Java Application as following give error.

Error/Output:

`command: [/bin/bash, -c, mysqldump -hlocalhost-u root -p123 some_database -r "/Users/Username/Workspace/backup.sql"]
/bin/bash: mysqldump: command not found
false`

Program code:

```
String cmd = "mysqldump -h" + dbHost + "-u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", cmd);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
System.out.println("command: " + pb.command());  
Process process = pb.start();
int processComplete = process.waitFor();
if (processComplete == 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I'm using AMPPS MySQL Installation.

[Update]

I think this issue is related to Netbeans. I'm testing from Netbeans. Seems Netbeans not load `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this path to execute mysqldump

`/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysqldump`

your command should be something like this

```
String cmd = "/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysqldump  -h" + dbHost + "-u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
```

Comment: I need a way to get the path from env or some place. Because this app is a cross platform one. Needs to work with Windows and Linux too.

Comment: Try running the same command as root user on mac. 
Could you confirm if your app requires sudo privs?